# How to prevent live/neutral/ground cables being swapped?

Tags: electrical, wiring, safety, appliances

A few years ago, I made the mistake of swapping the live and neutral wires on an appliance. The switch was only connected to the live wire, but since the wires were swapped, the whole circuit bypassed the switch and was live.

What are some safety precautions one can take to:

1. Prevent the wires from ever being swapped in the first place.
2. Verify that the wires have not been accidentally swapped.
3. Protect against electrocution in the case that (1) and (2) has not been able to catch the problem.

Assume that any wire may have been accidentally swapped (or not connected), not just the live and neutral wires.

I've seen a lot to questions asking what would happen if two of the wires are swapped, but haven't seen any regarding preventative and safety measures.

Comment: Don’t work on wiring if you don’t know what you are doing? Double check your work? What really are you looking for?

Comment: You mean individual wires, right? Cables are several wires wrapped in a sheath.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine Yes, the individual wires for live, neutral and ground.

Comment: @JonCuster I usually do a visual confirmation and some checks with multimeter, but I don't take apart appliances very often. I did manage to somehow swap the wires a few years ago, so I was wondering if there are any more rigorous precautions to account for human fallibility. Example use cases may be when reassembling/fixing appliances or replacing worn power cables.

Comment: Figure out what things you should not DIY and don't do them yourself. Household wiring is not rocket science, but you can certainly kill yourself, or others, or burn down buildings (with the potential of that also doing the former two things.)

Comment: you could integrate a common outlet tester circuit, it's just 3 LEDs and 3 resistors to normally light 2 of the three LEDs. You could use optocouplers instead of LEDs that would crowbar or open up the supply if a fault (hi where should be low, low where should be high) were detected.

Comment: The main safety precaution is to leave well alone, and get professional help, if you have to ask this question.

Comment: Were you rewiring the appliance or were you rewiring the household supply to the appliance?

Comment: This question is too broad. You might as well ask for tips on keeping your car on the right side of the road.

Comment: @FreeMan I'm mainly concerned with rewiring appliances. If I needed to rewire the household's supply, I would probably call an electrician. There's too many safety considerations for the latter.

Comment: As you've discovered, there are just as many safety considerations when working on an appliance. You're still dealing with full mains voltage in many parts.

Comment: @isherwood There seems to be good answers for (1) (follow electrical codes, color codes, take pictures, etc.) and (3) (GFCI/AFCI, turn off circuit and verify off, etc.). For (2), I was expecting a list of common mistakes, the hazard they pose, and how to detect them.

Comment: Broad _and_ open-ended. Two undesirable traits of questions on this site. Alas, also a rep-cow for those who want to post answers.

Comment: Despite having posted an answer that's _totally different_ than the 2 that were posted before mine, I'll 100% agree that this is _far_ too broad to fit here. It's not even well defined enough to know whether it's about house wiring or appliance wiring until we pulled that out after a dozen comments. The question also seems to be shifting after every answer that's posted, based on the OP's comments on each new answer that shows up. _Very_ poor fit for [diy.se], best taken to a general discussion board where broad open-ended wandering topics are the SOP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### First, school up and follow Code.

A lot of people try to "stretch" their skills when doing electrical work.  Don't do that - take your time to learn how to do good work.  Don't guess or freestyle.

Whether you know it or not, your area has an electrical code - a book of rules for installing electrical that you are required to follow.  I find some people are in denial about this.

The electrical codes will dictate to you which colors of wire must be used for live/hot versus neutral (versus ground, although ground is yellow/green or green almost everywhere).

In some areas, there was a legacy set of colors that was used prior to harmonization with EU rules, and then of course there are EU colors (light blue neutral).

If you are sure your area has no electrical codes, then use *El NEC* for 100-120V areas, and the EU codes for 220-240V areas.

Also, work should be tested/checked. Though when disciplines are followed correctly, problems are infrequent.   We have plug-in 3-light testers that confirm correct wiring in one action.

For hard-wired work,  you must use standard colors for the wires. When using *correct* multi-conductor cable, they will have the correct colors already.  If your rules allow using random colors of correct wires, then you need to "re-mark" the ends of each wire to mark it as neutral or ground, using colored paint, tape or sleeving of appropriate color.

Test with a volt meter.

For appliances, any approved appliance will be marked with the correct connections. Obey them.  If the appliance is not approved, don't use it.

### Second, follow good procedures.

Top of the list there is Lockout/Tagout.  That means turn it off, and throw a tag and lock on it so that somebody else doesn't turn it back on.  This is a basic discipline that keeps you from getting shocked (as you did).

Shut off the main disconnect or breaker to the entire electric service, because wiring defects are frequently present.  People especially novices get blind-sided by a variety of defects such as borrowed neutrals or unmarked MWBCs.  "Turning off the individual circuit breaker" only works if all prior work was done correctly.

You got shocked because Code was not followed *and* you did not turn off the power. That is two separate things, or two "layers in the Swiss cheese" if you use [that accident model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_cheese_model).

> How do I prevent the cables from ever being swapped in the first place?

Learn the electrical code and proper practices in the area you are working... and follow it faithfully.  Err on the side of learning too much.

And then, as you work, test.

> How do I verify that the cables have not been accidentally swapped?

Treat all past work as corrupted.  Open up every junction box and physically inspect it.  Use electrical testing devices such as a 3-lamp tester to confirm.

> How do I protect against electrocution in the case that (1) and (2) has not been able to catch the problem?

By good procedures: shut the power off at the main, and lockout-tagout if the environment makes that necessary.

And, use a recently verified tester to affirm that power is indeed off.

Comment: I can see how that will be useful for outlets, but how would one test if the power cord has been connected correctly and safely on an appliance/equipment before plugging it in, besides visual confirmation? Particularly if the live and neutral has been swapped somehow.

Comment: An example where this can become a hazard is on appliances with light bulb sockets, which could be live even with the switch turned off, if live/neutral are accidentally flipped.

Comment: Those three light testers work for sockets, but I can't see how they would test a re-wired appliance.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the confirmation. I guess something equivalent to polarity checking on a PAT tester would work for (2), although I'm not quite sure how it does it. It is quite an expensive device compared to outlet testers.

Comment: @aiwl - it may help us to know the country in question - different situations for different parts of the world. For example, in France, live and neutral don't mind getting mixed up - switches are double pole (a great safety feature), whereas in UK it's usually the live that's switched (which then becomes important when re-wiring.

Comment: @aiwl I edited to cover this.  You need to use approved appliances, which will be plainly marked for which connections are live, neutral and ground.  Use cables approved for purpose which will have standard colors, or individual wires of correct colors. Use a meter or neon tester to test polarity.

Answer (score 5):

Most wires for where it matters, hot, neutral, and ground are colour coded.

Neutral can only be white or sometimes grey, ground is bare or green, and hot can be most other colours(for North America).

#1 is something that can't be prevented, but check for.

#2 should be done for any job and tested for. Why most electrical jobs require an inspector to double check what you or an license electrician work on.

#3 Can't protect against stupid, but there safety features(GFCI/AFCI) that help.

Comment: What are the proper tests that needs to be done to ensure that all 3 cables are connected correctly? Could you elaborate on #2? Assume that basic tools like a multimeter are available.

Answer (score 4):

The individual wires within an appliance cable are often color coded or (with lamp cord, for example) have a pattern molded into the cable housing on one side.

- Before you disassemble:

  - Look at the color coding
  - Take a picture of it with your phone or other camera
  - Draw a sketch and label it
  - Do both of the above
  - Use a multimeter to test continuity so you know which color wire connects to which pin on the plug.
- When you're reassembling

  - Verify as you're reconnecting that you're matching the original
  - Once you've connected everything double check all your colors
  - Verify with the multimeter that the colors match the pins you identified in the "Before you disassemble" section.
  - To be extra safe, have someone else verify your work

Comment: As part of  - Before you disassemble - You can use a continuity tester to see which wire matches which pin on the plug end. Then after the cord is swapped out check it to make sure it's the same as before it was swapped.

Comment: Good call, @PlatinumGoose. Updated

Comment: @PlatinumGoose In the case where there is some "always on" component like a non-LED standby light or heating coil before the main circuit, there would be direct continuity between the live wire and the neutral pin on the plug (and vice versa) if both wires are not disconnected from the terminal block first. Taking a picture then disconnecting the cable from the terminal block first before measuring would help prevent that.